# DataGridViewComboBoxCell updated though bindings not immediately visible

Tags: winforms, datagridview

after text of a BindingList item bound to my DataGridViewComboBoxColumn is edited programatically the UI doesn't show it. 
PropertyChangeNotifications are working fine as viewing in a breakpoint shows cell.FormattedValue has already changed.

It will appear if I interact with the control (select row/sort/resize)

Calling dgv.Refresh() manually also works but this is dynamic binding code that isn't supposed to need to know what it is bound to.

looks like a DataGridView bug to me but maybe there is a setting I am missing

I don't see anything relevant in my init code except maybe to know that
dgv is ReadOnly and columns created with DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing

cbColumn.Datasource = BindingList < custom class like a KeyValuePair < int, string> with INotifyPropertyChanged>

cbColumn.ValueMember = name of int field

cbColumn.DisplayMember = name of text field

dgv cell populated with int of item being changed

text is edited on custom ORM which sends events to class managing multiple UI objects (some cbs some dgvs) that changes the actual BindingList item text.

this all works but the dgv just doesn't trigger its own refresh

Comment: show us the code where you edit the text programmatically, also show us how you binded the datagridview

Comment: added what I could without getting into detail on my layers of custom classes